# Hide button on asp.net wizard

Tags: asp.net, wizard

net wizard, and im tryng to hide the next button on some cases. My problem is that I can't seem to fin the button using WizardFindControl("") it always return null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently have this issue found out that you need to add StepNavigationTemplateContainerID$ before your control id

Check out this [blog](http://romsteady.blogspot.com/2007/08/howto-find-controls-in-wizard.html)

```
Button finishButton = Wizard1.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplateContainerID$FinishButton") as Button;
```

Answer (score 1):

to make alejandrobog's work, u must Convert to StepNavigation Template

```
<StepNavigationTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="StepPreviousButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="MovePrevious">Previous</asp:Button>
    <asp:Button ID="StepNextButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext">Next</asp:Button>
</StepNavigationTemplate>
```

then FindControl works

```
Button btnPre = (Button)Wizard1.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplateContainerID$StepPreviousButton");
btnPre.Visible = false;
Button btnNext = (Button)Wizard1.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplateContainerID$StepNextButton");
btnNext.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((Button)Wizard1.FindControl("FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("btnBack")).Visible = false;
```

`FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID` could also be `StepNavigationTemplateContainerID` - thats a fix name, **don't** use the ID you gave `<asp:WizardStep ID="Step2"`

`Wizard1` is the ID of your asp:Wizzard

`btnBack` is the ID of your `asp:Button` like
 `<FinishNavigationTemplate> <asp:Button ID="btnBack"`