# Wizard Control Disable Buttons

Tags: .net, aspwizard

How can I disable the Back and Confirm buttons in my 'Final' step of my Wizard control ?

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard" runat="server"  DisplayCancelButton="True"
StepPreviousButtonText="Back" FinishPreviousButtonText="Back"
FinishCompleteButtonText="Confirm" >

<WizardSteps>
.....
<asp:WizardStep ID="ConfirmStep" runat="server" Title="Confirm Request"
StepType="Finish" >
<asp:WizardStep>
....
</WizardSteps>
</asp:Wizard>



Protected Sub Wizard_FinishButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
System.Web.UI.WebControls.WizardNavigationEventArgs) Handles Wizard.FinishButtonClick
.......

'I want to disable the Confirm and Back button here after displaying the error message.
e.Cancel = True

End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971222/hide-button-on-asp-net-wizard

Answer (score 0):

Select Your Wizard and Convert it to StartNavigationTempltae. and then in your aspx page

```
<StartNavigationTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="StartNextButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" 
Text="Next" Visible="false" />
</StartNavigationTemplate>
```

set visibility off to start or whatever button you want to hide